# Why is there a difference between urls submitted to a sitemap and urls in the google index?

Tags: google-search-console

[image]

The crawl report shows this:
"HTTP ‎(1)‎ In Sitemaps ‎(5)‎ Not found ‎(993)‎ Restricted by robots.txt ‎(487,544)‎"

So the discrepancy between 50,000 and 44,592 isn't coming from that.  Are there any obvious reasons?

Comment: `Restricted by robots.txt ‎(487,544)` : 5,408 missing urls can't be in there ?

Comment: @Chouchenos no, because those would appear in the part where it says (x) in sitemaps.

Answer (score 7):

I think it is simply that Google does not necessarily index all the URLs submitted. The submitted sitemap is advisory, it is then up to the Search Engines to determine whether those URLs should be (or are worthy to be) indexed.

Or, may be Google just hasn't gotten round to checking/indexing those other pages yet? By look of your screenshot you only submitted the Sitemap *today*?!

Comment: No, the sitemap is downloaded every day by google.  That is just showing the last time it was downloaded.

Comment: @Michael So those 5,000+ pages aren't a recent addition then?

Answer (score 3):

The difference lies in Google's priorities: you may have pages in your sitemap, however, for whatever reason (be it lack of incoming links to deep content, lack of in-site links, delays in posting back index data, et cetera) Google either doesn't have the content indexed or isn't showing you what's *actually* indexed.

> We're aware that we sometimes return
>   erroneous estimates for the number of
>   results that return for a query, and
>   we're working to improve these
>   estimates.

[Features: Incorrect search results count](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=38)

Given that Google doesn't make it a priority to show you exactly how many pages are in its index for a given search, I'd say it's just a matter of Google failing to show you an accurate picture of its index.

Comment: Google's estimates might be inaccurate, but I would have said it was quite probable that not all submitted pages will be indexed.

Comment: @w3d - I'd say it's more likely that Google has *more* pages indexed than it ostensibly reports (pages disallowed by robots.txt are still indexed in some form, if only to track the number of links directed at the off-limits URI, et cetera) - it's just not in Google's interest to reveal *everything* it knows :)